# Get terminal output into code

Tags: c, linux, terminal, output

I wrote a program that compiles and runs an external program(prog1.c). And I want to get the output of the prog1.c somehow. 
for example if prog1.c is `printf("HELLO");` and prints HELLO to the terminal, I want this output to get to a variable in my program or a file.
I saw somewhere something about pipe, but I dont know this command much and dont know if this is the right way.

Anyone can help me, direct me or show me an example?
Thank you!

Comment: Search for "pipe", "popen" or "redirection".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [freopen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/freopen/) you can redirect your `printf` output to file.

```
freopen("c:\\output\\output.txt","w",stdout);
printf("write in file using printf"); //this will be printed to file, not to console
```

If you want to understand more you can see my [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T_iJZPBUzbY&list=PLkes6AxGmNZ7AuvPXe9WfwKNIzNPVEg-D&index=14) on this.

In this example I have not used pipe, but redirected standard output to file rather than console.

Comment: Thank you! It looks realy easy to use

Comment: @marcopolo it opens file in writing mode.

Comment: @marcopolo I have provided link for freopen reference, and my video tutorial too.

Comment: Yea, I accpeted. When I saw it it was too soon to accept

Answer (score 0):

you can also use pipe (and fork) to redirect outpout from prog1 to your input in the other prog,
and check waitpid to catch return value too